# authorizing a google maps api v3 key for access from https pages

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was using a key that worked for me on http pages but when I tried to use it from an http page it did not work.
It just showed the following message:

> "Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The 
>   provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized 
>   for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the 
>   owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key 
>   here: ..."

Within the apis console I have set up the Referers: to `*.mydomain.com/*`

Only after adding `https://mydomain.com/page` did it start to work when accessed from the https page.

Is this a bug or a feature?
Shouldn't `*.mydomain.com/*` also cover for `https://mydomain.com/page` ?

Answer (score 0):

No. I believe it's not a bug and the referrer means the domain, not the protocol as well. It should be explicitly documented, but it's easily set up, as you found.

I suspect the reason for its omission from the documentation is simply that the Console key is a recent innovation and the docs haven't caught up (a common failing over the last five years). A beneficial side-effect may be that you could use different keys for `https` and `http` to separate out statistics reporting or even make use of different quotas.

Comment: "referrer means the domain, not the protocol as well" ? But then I would expect `*.mydomain.com/*` to match the "refferer" if its `https://mydomain.com/page` ....

Comment: What you expect to happen may not be how the API Console works, as evidenced by your findings. That doesn't mean it's a bug. It's just not working how *you* expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Andrew Leach.

This is what [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) says about hosting a google map from HTTPS pages:

> HTTPS
>
> If your application is an HTTPS application, you may instead wish to load the Google Maps JavaScript API over HTTPS:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It does not mention about using different keys for HTTP and HTTPS for same domain. *(I think because it is upto you to decide whether you want to host your page on HTTP or HTTPS. If you change your mind to alter protocols, logging will be starting from 0, as both are now different applications.)* Make sure you are doing exactly what they are asking to do, then give a shout for BUG !

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following referers to make it work:

```
https://mydomain.com/*

https://www.mydomain.com/*

http://www.mydomain.com/*

http://mydomain.com/*
```

**Why all these referers ?**

Users of your website may access your site using any of these urls. So its better to give them as referers so that you can avoid these kind of errors.